# scrollable flex item - how to get width equals to content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a section with vertical long menu and a section with small content, so I would like to have height dimension equals to the smallest one and long menu with scroll bar.

With pure CSS, I try this:

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header,
.footer,
.content,
.sidebar,
.flex-box {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.scroll {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="header">
    <p>This is the horizontal header bar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="scroll">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>item 9</li>
            <li>item 10</li>
            <li>item 11</li>
            <li>item 12</li>
            <li>item 13</li>
            <li>item 14</li>
            <li>item 15</li>
            <li>item 16</li>
            <li>item 17</li>
            <li>item 18</li>
            <li>item 19</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer netus interdum dis at et. In mauris nunc tempor Curabitur consequat tortor urna nonummy montes nibh. Egestas et Nunc tristique ullamcorper faucibus libero commodo sociis sagittis laoreet. Odio eros dignissim
        et laoreet volutpat Donec massa id metus fermentum. Lorem nibh eros Integer In ullamcorper Donec sed quis non condimentum. Lorem non Phasellus Curabitur vel.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't give the right dimension to sidebar, that I would like to have equals to his content.

So I try another solution, but in this case, content dimension is wrong and sidebar overlap content.

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header,
.footer,
.content,
.sidebar,
.flex-box {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  direction: rtl;
  color: white
}

.menu {
  direction: ltr;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>This is the horizontal header bar</p>
</div>
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="scroll">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
        <li>item 8</li>
        <li>item 9</li>
        <li>item 10</li>
        <li>item 11</li>
        <li>item 12</li>
        <li>item 13</li>
        <li>item 14</li>
        <li>item 15</li>
        <li>item 16</li>
        <li>item 17</li>
        <li>item 18</li>
        <li>item 19</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer netus interdum dis at et. In mauris nunc tempor Curabitur consequat tortor urna nonummy montes nibh. Egestas et Nunc tristique ullamcorper faucibus libero commodo sociis sagittis laoreet. Odio eros dignissim
      et laoreet volutpat Donec massa id metus fermentum. Lorem nibh eros Integer In ullamcorper Donec sed quis non condimentum. Lorem non Phasellus Curabitur vel.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

Finally I add a simple javascript that dinamically change sidebar width dimension to vmenu dimension and this works, but I would like to find out how to achive this without javascript.

Any other approach is welcome, but as you can see I would like to do not insert fixed width or height directive and have a layout which fits the width size of the sidebar content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position:absolute is the culprit, you can remove it and consider another trick. Make the scroll element with a height equal to 0 so it will overflow. Its parent element will stretch by default inside the flex container so it will fill the height defined by content then you add `overflow:auto`.

After that simply keep `flex:1` on the content

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header,
.footer,
.content,
.sidebar,
.flex-box {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.scroll {
  height:0;
  display: flex;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="header">
    <p>This is the horizontal header bar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="scroll">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>long item</li>
            <li>item 10</li>
            <li>item 11</li>
            <li>item 12</li>
            <li>item 13</li>
            <li>item 14</li>
            <li>item 15</li>
            <li>item 16</li>
            <li>item 17</li>
            <li>item 18</li>
            <li>item 19</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer netus interdum dis at et. In mauris nunc tempor Curabitur consequat tortor urna nonummy montes nibh. Egestas et Nunc tristique ullamcorper faucibus libero commodo sociis sagittis laoreet. Odio eros dignissim
        et laoreet volutpat Donec massa id metus fermentum. Lorem nibh eros Integer In ullamcorper Donec sed quis non condimentum. Lorem non Phasellus Curabitur vel.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
    <div class="block">My Block</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
.column{
  background: #EAEAEA;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
} 
.block{
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. Column with block element doesn't fit the block width and you give 100% height that doesn't match my layout. Take a look to the accepted answer and run code snippet to view what I would like to have.